# Xcode - The property may not be available in this context

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autocomplete

Looks like the Xcode introduces more and more new problems to developers.
Does anyone know what the hell is this issue and how to get rid of it?: **The property is defined on XXX, and may not be available in this context.**

The property exists in this scope and the code runs without any problems, but auto-complete is broken as always... [image]

Comment: Cant you see the question? How to get rid of this issue or why it happens?

Comment: No I completely failed to see those two questions in your text above. I do think this new behavior has to do with the new functionality in Xcode to automatically add a new `import XYZ` if you add something from XYZ in your code.

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this??

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 13 / iOS 15. It is something in your project, please provide minimal reproducible example or access to project code. What is mapView, what is map, what is tables? Etc.

Comment: Yes, I do not face this issue with the latest iOS and Xcode.

Comment: I face this issue quite often with Xcode 13 (only saw it once I upgraded to Xcode 13). I'm moisture what mapView is either, I'm just noticing I'm getting similar errors that pop up every once in awhile. Hard to predict when...

Comment: please add more context, where this code runs? what are you trying to do with code?

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this issue by checking pods versions installed, upgrade or downgrade pods to access this method.
In project folder delete pods folder and reinstall it.
Check the pods versions twice which is needed to be update.

Answer (score 1):

So what I'm noticing is that ever since upgrading from Xcode 12 to Xcode 13, instead of a property not displaying in auto-complete (because it is inaccessible in the current scope), it seems that Xcode 13 displays it in auto-complete with the warning/error that the property may not be available in the context. In other words, Xcode 13 seems to recognize the property exists somewhere but, in theory, shouldn't be available in the current scope

In short, I suppose this (seemingly new?) warning is basically Xcode telling you it thinks the property isn't available in the scope but can't be 100% sure, so it allows you to use it at your own risk (although usually Xcode is right and you mistakenly think it should be accessible when it isn't).

Answer (score 1):

You might get that message if you're accessing a property from a header inside a framework, and the header is not added to the framework's umbrella header.

In that case, the solution is to add the header to the umbrella header.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with undoActionName and redoActionName.  The fix was easy - I simply added undoManager. in front.  undoManager inherits from UndoManager.  So, try putting the class XXX.table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access Objective-C code from a Swift file, make sure you have added the Objective-C header file in `YourProject-Bridging-Header.h`